# How to get MongoDB collection sharding config using Node.js driver?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, node-mongodb-native

I need to retrieve information about a MongoDB collection's sharding configuration, specifically the `shardKey` and `unique` fields. While I can easily obtain this information using the `sh.status()` command in the MongoDB shell, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this using the MongoDB Node.js driver.

Is it possible to retrieve this information using the Node.js driver, and if so, how can I do it?

I already tried collection.stats(), but no luck. There is a `shards` object in returned object value but fieds I need aren't there.

```
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const stats = await db.collection(collectionName).stats();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what are the information you required by you can run the  `adminCommand` equivalent in nodejs using `runCommand`

e.g.

```
db.runCommand({ listShards: 1 })
```

The list of commands u can run for sharding is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/#sharding-commands).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Unfortunately, `db.command({ listShards: 1 })` returns only shards info like host and state.
And I need a sharding config for a collection, at least the collection's shard key.
When you are enabling sharding for a collection you are using [shardCollection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/shardCollection/#shardcollection) function with a key parameter.
I need to retrieve that key value.

Comment: Unfortunately in the mongodb documentation @ https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/ they did not mention about retrieval of shard key, may I know what exactly u r trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
db.getSiblingDB("config").getCollection("collections").find()
```

It provides the shard key. To get unique fields, you need to query the indexes. Would be this:

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
```

You may also have a look at collections `config.database`, `config.shards` and , `config.chunks`